Iframe error when loading from localhost net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
I have a web page that has a website that is loaded in an iframe like so.
<iframe id="example" src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>

It has an API that you can use to communicate with it through post messages.
If I post a message to it with a URL to a resource it will process that resource. It works on a remote domain. But I'm testing locally. When I use http://localhost/resource.txt I get an error in the console from the embedded website:
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
I'm guessing this may be a CORs issue. Is it possible to set the iframe so that it can load the resource locally?

Think about how the server attempting to make the request will interpret localhost

You just need to use the external IP address of your local machine, rather than localhost.
